# youtube channel ID or name from URL

Tags: regex

I'd like to get a youtube channel ID or name from a youtube URL with a single regex.
URLs can be vary like:

(#1 .../c/{name}) `https://www.youtube.com/c/aespa` or

(#2 .../{name}) `http://www.youtube.com/GIRLSGENERATION` or

(#3 .../channel/{ID}) `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzgxx_DM2Dcb9Y1spb9mUJA/featured`

What I already have now is do the job for case #1 and #3:

```
preg_match('/(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com)\/(channel|c)\/(?<name>[A-Za-z0-9-_\.]+)/im', $url, $matches);
```

I'd be great if the `/channel|c` part could be optional so the case #2 will work too. It might be a problem that regex must check for `/channel|c` first, and if there is no matches, it should check the URL against the `/channel|c` part (Otherwise, `/c` or `/channel` string will be considered as *name* parameter).

Any advise appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution which uses a regex pattern having an alternation to cover the three expected types of YouTube URL:

```php
$inputs = ["https://www.youtube.com/c/aespa", "http://www.youtube.com/GIRLSGENERATION", "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzgxx_DM2Dcb9Y1spb9mUJA/featured"];
$names = [];
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    preg_match_all("/https?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/(?:channel\/(.*?)\/featured|(?:.*\/)*(.+))/", $input, $matches);
    array_push($names, $matches[1][0] ?: $matches[2][0]);
    print_r($matches);
}
print_r($names);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aespa
    [1] => GIRLSGENERATION
    [2] => UCzgxx_DM2Dcb9Y1spb9mUJA
)
```

For an explanation of the regex, the first portion of the alternation attempts to match the more specific `/channel/{...}/feature` variant.  That failing, the regex attempts to match and capture the final component of the URL as being the name.

Comment: thank you, i made a mistake with `/featured` part, i just want to explain that some URLs are ends with any appendix like `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzgxx_DM2Dcb9Y1spb9mUJA/featured` or `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzgxx_DM2Dcb9Y1spb9mUJA/` or `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzgxx_DM2Dcb9Y1spb9mUJA/anything-else-may-come-here` Can you edit your answer like that? Btw it's a very noice solution!

Comment: Would also be nice to support channel alias URLs beginning with an "@" like https://www.youtube.com/@youtubecreators